# Can SSO config only import selective SettingsFileGenerator.xml settings?

Tags: biztalk, btdf

The SettingsFileGenerator.xml file seems to have two purposes.  One is to set the SSO Config and the other is to dynamically replace settings in the PortBindingsMaster.xml for each environment.   I am replacing dozens of values in the PortBindingMaster.xml file that don't need to also be stored in the SSO config.  Is there a standard way to specify which settings I want to be stored in the SSO config so I don't store a lot of extra values there?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking is not directly supported.  There a couple of workarounds though.

You can maintain a separate settings file for runtime only settings and use a custom CustomPostDeployTarget task to Exec SSOSettingsFileImport.exe with you runtime settings file.

Or, you can use a set of UpdateSSOConfigItem elements as referenced here: [Deploy Configuration Settings into SSO](http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?DeployConfigurationSettingsintoS.html).